# How can I fix this stacking UI bug?

Tags: interface

I'm practicing rigging/animating, and I need to open the dope sheet editor, but the button to change what editor is open is currently blocked by the mode selector drop down. I closed and reopened, reset my UI to factory default, saved as, etc, and nothing will move it back to where it's supposed to be. When I open a new file, it's perfectly fine.

Here's how it looks:[image: Bugged UI]

And here's how it's supposed to look, and how it looks when I open a new file. [image: Correct UI]